# How to use 2 argument on the Lambda function with .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Is it possible to make this code faster?

```
    for i in range (len (data)):
        column_name = data['Name'].values[i]
        if data['Market'].values[i] == 'P':
            market = 'Local'
        else:
            market = 'Oversea'
        data['Momentum'].values[i] = self.Factor_Model (column_name, market)
```

I am not used to `.apply()` and lambda functions. Could you guide me how to change above code to like below?

```
data['Momentum'] = data.apply(lambda row: self.Factor_Model(row['Name'],lambda row: if row['Market'].values == 'P' ))
```

Thank you for your guide in advance.

Comment: Post your data and expected output.. just looking at your apply is hard to answer with a degree of confidence

Comment: data['Name'] has various str type  , data['Market'] just has 'P' or 'Q',  data['Momentum'] should be fillin as a result of Factor_Model's return and Factor_Model use data['Name'] and data['Market'] values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call `.apply()` with `axis=1` to operate on rows. And then pass each item from the Series to the function directly.

```
data['Location'] = np.where(data['Market'] == 'P', 'Local', 'Oversea')

data['Momentum'] = data.apply(lambda x: Factor_Model(x['Name'], x['Location']), axis=1)
```